# Plot | PDF | UniformDistribution ~ Rookie problem displaying the PDFs

Tags: plotting, distributions, visualization

I haven't used Mathematica for some time; and I think, I am having a mental block... All I am trying to do is demonstrate UniformDistribution PDFs for x ~ {0, 1}, {0, 2} and {0, 4} as three seperate lines, but I keep getting five lines (?). Please point the blind in the right direction.

```
Plot[
 Table[
   PDF[
     UniformDistribution[{0, max}], x]
   , {max, {1, 2, 4}}
   ] // Evaluate
 , {x, 0, 4}
 , Axes -> False
 , Frame -> True
 , PlotStyle -> {Red, Black, Blue}
 , FrameTicks -> None
 , FrameLabel -> Style[ "Uniform Distribution", 12, Bold]
 ]
```

[image: uniform distribution pdfs]

Comment: Try the option `Exclusions -> None` and/or including the `FrameTicks`.

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what `Exclusions` sure did highlight what's going on... Now, I need to figure out how to plot my lines ignoring the exclusions. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is purely a visual one: *Mathematica* is plotting the 3 PDF's you requested. However it LOOKS like 4 lines are being plotted, because the 4th line is actually a plot of the pdf when the density is 0 (outside the various domains of support). If you showed the Axes etc, this would be apparent.

For comparison, here is how it is done with the *mathStatica* package for Mathematica.  In your case, you have  $X \sim \text{Uniform}(0,b)$ with pdf $f(x)$:

```
 f = 1/b;        domain[f] = {x, 0, b} && {b > 0};
```

And plot the density at the desired values of parameter $b$:

```
 PlotDensity[f /. b -> {1, 2, 4}]
```

[image]

---

For a solution using just in-built Mma commands, I would suggest changing tack slightly, and instead of:

- plotting a Table of pdf's, to instead ...
- Table a plot of each pdf (plotting each over its respective domain of support).

For instance:

```
Show[
    Table[
       Plot[PDF[UniformDistribution[{0, max}], x], {x, 0, max}, PlotStyle -> max],
          {max, {1, 2, 4}}], 
    PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "pdf"}]
```

[image]

... does the trick.

Comment: Could you provide an alternative solution? I am afraid I do not have the `PlotDensity` function :)

Comment: Above should do what you seek